# Bring up desktop app from Start(or metro) screen in Windows 8 programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8

I am writing a LOB WPF program which gives some text alert (just simple `MessageBox.Show();`) to user.

But as you imagine, the desktop app that I wrote does NOT be **displayed** to user unless the user switches to Desktop mode by clicking "Desktop" tile.

I tried to use [InputSimulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) in order to press Win+D virtually, but exception was thrown.

How can I bring up desktop app to foreground programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you aren't writing an additional Windows Store/Metro app as well...you just want the user to see the alert raised by your WPF desktop app even if they are currently in a full-screen Windows Store/Metro app and not on the desktop.

To solve this problem, I recommend using the toast notification system.  You can send toast notifications from either Windows Store apps or desktop apps, so your WPF app could raise a toast notification instead of using your text alert/MessageBox.Show() mechanism.  This toast notification will be displayed to the user no matter where they are...on the desktop, on the Start screen, in a Windows Store/Metro app...does this solve your problem?

Here is the documentation on [sending toast notifications from desktop apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779727.aspx#sending_toast_notifications_from_desktop_apps).  It also links to a [quickstart code walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh802768.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but not even an alert, is it possible to show the desktop app to the foreground programatically?

Comment: No, there is no way for your desktop app to supercede what the user is doing and come to the foreground.  Notifications are the best way to do this.