# Windows 8 C# Force Desktop View

Tags: c#, windows-8

I have a C# program that shows HTML based notifications on the user's desktop. This has worked out pretty well until Windows 8 came along. The problem with Windows 8 is that users can only see the messages if they are using a desktop application. Does anyone know of a way to force windows to return to the desktop view?

Comment: what if you explicitly set focus to window on desktop?

Comment: consider using a toast notification instead

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bring up desktop app from Start(or metro) screen in Windows 8 programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959958/bring-up-desktop-app-from-startor-metro-screen-in-windows-8-programatically)

Answer (score 1):

In previous versions you could use the API function to set a topmost window. This was annoying at best as if you were typing or concentrating on something, the other window popped up. So then using systray notifications became a better way of doing this.

Windows 8 brings up additional questions - what happens when an app is running or the start screen is open. If you were to return to the desktop you would potentially force the other application to suspend by making it lose focus without the user necessarily wanting that. I'd consider it a bad design if I was the user and in the middle of the Windows Store app experience. Especially if the WinRT app didn't have proper code to resume exactly where I left off.

So the next question then is how to notify the user. Toast notifications fit the bill here.
You'll want to add a reference to Windows.Winmd, ensure you register a shortcut to your app on the start screen (doesn't have to be visible), and then simply create the notification and assign the handlers in your app as per:

[Quickstart: Sending a toast notification from the desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/Hh802768%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)